# How to modify proguard-android-optimize.txt with AndroidStudio 2.2?

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard, android-proguard, android-studio-2.2

With Android Studio 2.2 and [the new build system](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system), the ProGuard files available in `$ANDROID_HOME` are no longer used:

> 2.2.0-alpha4 (2016/6/23) 
>   ... 
>   ProGuard files returned by `getDefaultProguardFile` are distributed with
>   the plugin now, the ones in `$ANDROID_HOME` are no longer used.

I used to use a modified version of `proguard-android-optimize.txt` suitable for my needs. Now, the file `proguard-android-optimize.txt-2.2.2` located in `<project_path>\build\intermediates\proguard-files` is generated at build time.

So how can I do now, should there be a way?

Of course, I can (probably?) modify each and every project-specific `.pro` files to reach the same goal, but the advantage of changing `proguard-android-optimize.txt` was to do it once for all.

Comment: I'm curious if you can just add another ProGuard file to the `proguardFiles` property from outside the project; `proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro', '/path/to/proguard-custom-optimize.pro'`.

Comment: @Bryan Oh, I did not even think about that!! `proguardFiles '../../my-proguard-android-optimize.txt', 'proguard-rules.pro'` works perfectly, it did the trick :) Would you marry me? Otherwise, please just make an answer of your comment, I'll upvote it 3 times and accept it twice  :)

Comment: Glad it worked! I wasn't sure if it would, didn't have time to test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a ProGuard file to the `proguardFiles` property from outside of the project:

```
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
        'proguard-rules.pro', '/path/to/proguard-optimize.pro'
```

Comment: I actually did not test exactly that but `proguardFiles '../../my-proguard-android-optimize.txt', 'proguard-rules.pro'` instead. `my-proguard-android-optimize.txt` is a derivation of the automatically generated `proguard-android-optimize.txt-2.2.2`. It is stored outside the project directory and this is no problem, this works great. Thanks!